# Show PyQt5 elements from inside Dash callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, plotly-dash

In my Python Dash app I would like to show some PyQt5 window pop-ups.
These are activated from within in a callback.

Unfortunately, when the pop-ups are shown, I get this warning in the console:

**WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.**

My question: how can I create a QApplication in the main() thread if it is called from inside a Python Dash callback?

Below you can find the code which represents a mwe. If you run this snippet, you will see the warning. Apparently, when QApplication is activated from within a callback, it is not run on the main thread (my guess is that app.run_server() is already running on the main thread). How can I modify it so the QApplication is in the main thread?

The example is similar to
[Use Dash (plot.ly) in PyQt5 GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522463/use-dash-plot-ly-in-pyqt5-gui)
but is not the same (I want pyqt5 in Dash, not Dash in pyqt5).

```
import os, dash
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    #some Qpop up
    pass

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    #button which, if pressed, created a QApplication in a non-main thread
    html.Button("show pop up", id="button"),
    html.H2(children='', id='result')
    ])

#The callback which creates the pop up I want to show.
#This is activated when the button "show pop up" is pressed, and causes the warning to appear
@app.callback(
Output(component_id='result', component_property='children'),
[Input(component_id='button', component_property='n_clicks')]
)   
def popUp(n_clicks):
    if not n_clicks:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication([os.getcwd()])
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()
    return "You saw a pop-up"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: You must be precise in your question, you also must not show code without explaining in detail what you want

Comment: Ok, I edited it. Hopefully it is now better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to run Dash in the secondary thread and send notifications to the GUI through signals as I show below (this answer is based on [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085804/6622587)):

```py
import functools
import os
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closed.emit()
        super().closeEvent(event)


class Manager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._view = None

    @property
    def view(self):
        return self._view

    def init_gui(self):
        self._view = MainWindow()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_popup(self):
        if self.view is not None:
            self.view.show()


qt_manager = Manager()

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Hello Dash"),
        html.Button("show pop up", id="button"),
        html.H2(children="", id="result"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="result", component_property="children"),
    [Input(component_id="button", component_property="n_clicks")],
)
def popUp(n_clicks):
    if not n_clicks:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    qt_manager.view.closed.connect(loop.quit)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
        qt_manager, "show_popup", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection
    )
    loop.exec_()

    return "You saw a pop-up"


def main():
    qt_app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if qt_app is None:
        qt_app = QtWidgets.QApplication([os.getcwd()])
    qt_app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    qt_manager.init_gui()
    threading.Thread(
        target=app.run_server, kwargs=dict(debug=False), daemon=True,
    ).start()

    return qt_app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Ok so this solves my question. However, it gets stuck in this qt_app.exec_() which doesn’t respond to my ctr+c. Is there a way to safely exit my program?